# Changing view controller to tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab based application with 2 tabs (HomeViewController and SettingsViewController).

On the SettingsViewController I have a button that will take the user to a third view (ChangeSomeSettingController).

On that third view, I have a TableView with this function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    ...
    let settingsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController
    self.presentViewController(settingsViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

This will move the user back to the SettingsViewController. However, I am not able to get the tab bar to display at the bottom of the screen like it is when I first load the application.

How can I go back to the SettingsViewController and keep the tabs at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `presentViewController:animated:completion:` will present `SettingsViewController` modally. What you need is a UINavigationController flow.

1) Add create `UITabBarController`
[image]

2) Select the item(UIViewController) that will has a `UINavigationControler` flow.

3) Delete it

4) Add `UITableViewController`

5) Add the new `UITableViewController` to the UITabBarController
[image]

6) Select the `UITableViewController` and embed in(Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller) to a Navigation Controller.
[image]

7) Add a `UIViewController` and add a segue(Show) between `UITableViewController` and `UIViewController`

8) The result final result should be something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In ChangeSomeSettingController, if you pushViewController from SettingViewController, you should call

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

or if you want to back to SettingViewController

```
//back to root view controller from navigation
navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
// you should call to tabbar view controller 
UITabbarViewController *tabbarVC = (UITabbarViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController;
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; // 1 is index of SettingViewController
```

This's example for me, with your problem you can modify to adapt your requirement. hope this help for you.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
self.presentViewController(settingsViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

will not move back the user to settings VC, it will present a new instance of the settings VC, which ofcourse covers the tab bar.

You need to push the VC when you select the tabs, so you don't have to present them again if you want to go back.

If you don't want a navigation controller, then you should present the tab bar controller instead of settings vc.